# Using method of undetermined coefficients, why was this particular solution chosen for this wave equation problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a wave equation with a periodic source:

$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} + \cos{\omega t}$

We have Dirichlet boundary conditions ($u(0,t) = 0, u(\pi, t) = 0, t > 0$), and initial condition $u(x,0) = 0, \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0) = 0$.

We are asked to use the method of eigenfunction expansion, where $u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n^{''}(t) + n^2 B_n(t) = \frac{2(1+(-1)^{n+1})}{n\pi}\cos(\omega t)$.

We need $B_n(t)$ to be in resonance with the source where $\omega = 1$. Therefore, we use $n = 1$.

$B_1^{''}(t) + B_1(t) = \frac{4}{\pi}\cos(t)$.

The "guessed" particular solution is $B_p(t) = a\cos(t) + b\sin(t) + ct\sin(t)$

Why did we choose the term $ct\sin(t)$ and not $c\sin(t)$? Is it because the homogenous solution already has $b\sin(t)$?

Comment: I think the guess should be $$B_{p} = a \cos(t) + b \color{red}t \cos(t) + c \sin(t)$$ because your inhomogeneous term is a cosine. Perhaps it is a typo.

Comment: Where does "We need $B_n(t)$ to be in resonance with the source" come from? Is that by some boundary conditions or some arbitrary restriction of the task?

Comment: I corrected the ODE, it should be $(1+(−1)^{1+1})$. And yes, the resonance with source is an arbitrary restriction on the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular solution $B_{1,p}(t)$ of
$$
B_1''(t)+B_1(t)=\frac{4}\pi\cos(t)
$$
has, because of the observed/constructed resonance, the trial form
$$
B_{1,p}(t)=at\cos(t)+bt\sin(t)
$$
by the method of undetermined coefficients. Computation should show that $a=0$ and $b=\frac2{\pi}$. Then note that, since $t\sin t=O(t^2)$, this already satisfies the initial conditions $B_1(0)=B_1'(0)=0$, so that it is already the solution.